# Outlook using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, outlook.application

I would like to know the time i.e when the email was readed using VBScript.
Could anyone help me to figurout this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have Outlook installed on the machine that is running the script, you could use Outlook Automation. Here's a MS kb article that might help you get started: [Programming examples for referencing items and folders in Outlook 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208520)

And then look at the [MailItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210946%28v=office.11%29.aspx) object which might contain the information you need.